# I cannot boot Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, multi-boot

Last week I installed Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 alongside Windows 10 following [this guide.](http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/)

After installation, I have been unable to access Windows 10. When I boot using Windows Bootloader it goes from "Preparing automatic repair" to "Diagnosing this PC" to a blue screen that says automatic repair couldn't repair your PC". It then goes to a screen which looks like this: [image] I have tried many of the troubleshooting options, including the "Exit to Windows 10", "Repair disk", and restoring from a restore point. All of them lead to a screen with the spinning dots constantly loooping, which I have let go for an hour with no results. Is there any way I could get back into Windows 10 without having to reset or uninstall my system?
[Here is my boot-repair output.](http://paste2.org/wYemgFnA)

Thanks for the help.

Edit: I am using an Acer Aspire E5-574G

Comment: Just our of curiosity, have you considered running Ubuntu as a virtual machine inside Windows 10, utilizing a free hypervisor like VirtualBox or Hyper-V?  To be honest, we see a **lot** of questions within the Super User realm from people who encounter problems while they attempt to dual-boot Windows along with their favorite Linux distro.

Comment: That would probably have been the best option but it is too late now.